# How to Get Element Id in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm new in android things. I want to ask this question. How can I get `R.id` from component in `RecycleViewCartAdapter.java` to `DaftarCartFragment.java`?

I really need help. Thank you very much.

---

Here's my **`DaftarCardFragment.java`** code

```
package tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.fragments.cart;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.R;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.adapters.RecycleViewCartAdapter;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.adapters.RecycleViewPesananAdapter;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.helpers.RestServiceClass;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.helpers.RestServiceInterface;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.models.Login.Login;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.models.Mobile.Order.Order;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.models.SalesTrackers.SalesTrackers;

public class DaftarCartFragment extends Fragment {

    public RestServiceInterface restServiceInterface;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(final Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daftar_cart, container, false);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String test = preferences.getString("userData", "");
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Login login = g.fromJson(test, Login.class);

        restServiceInterface = RestServiceClass.getClient().create(RestServiceInterface.class);
        Call<List<Order>> calls = restServiceInterface.shoppingCart(login.getBranchId().toString(), login.getEmployeeId().toString());
        calls.enqueue(new Callback<List<Order>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<Order>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<Order>> response) {
                try {
                    int sum = 0;
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Order>>(){}.getType();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(response.body(), type);
                    List<Order> salesTrackers = gson.fromJson(json, type);
                    mAdapter = new RecycleViewCartAdapter(salesTrackers, getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
                    rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                    //Hitung total harga
//                    for (int i = 0; i < salesTrackers.size(); i++) {
//                        int qty = (Integer) salesTrackers.get(i).getQuantity100();
//                        sum += salesTrackers.get(i).getTotal() * qty;
//                    }

                } catch (ClassCastException ce) {
                    ce.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                    ne.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<Order>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    /*
    VIEWHOLDER CLASS
     */
    public class RecyclerVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        Integer id;
        TextView produkName;
        TextView produkCode;
        TextView category;
        TextView warehouseCategory;
        TextView price100;
        TextView price90;
        TextView price60;
        TextView price30;
        EditText itemQuantity;
        Button detailButton;
        TextView buttonPlus;
        TextView buttonMinus;
        ImageView trashIcon;

        // ImageView imageView;

        public RecyclerVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            produkName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

            produkCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_code);

            category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_category);

            warehouseCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_warehouseCategory);

            price100 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            price90 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            price60 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            price30 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            itemQuantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);

            buttonPlus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_button_plus);

            buttonMinus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_button_minus);

            detailButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_detail_button);

            trashIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.trash_icon);
            //imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my **`RecycleViewCartAdapter.java`** code

```
package tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.List;

import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.R;
//import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.fragments.detail.DetailProdukFragment;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.fragments.detail.DetailProdukFragment;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.models.Mobile.Order.Order;
import tech.agronum.kitchenwaremobile.models.Mobile.Product.Product;

public class RecycleViewCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewCartAdapter.RecyclerVH> {

    public  static List<Order> mOrderList = null;

    Product inventory;
    String[] spacecrafts;
    Context context;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public RecycleViewCartAdapter(List<Order> order, FragmentManager _fragmentManager) {
        mOrderList = order;
        fragmentManager = _fragmentManager;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.component_card_cart,parent,false);
        return new RecyclerVH(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerVH holder, int i) {
        final Order order = mOrderList.get(i);
        final String id = order.getInventoryBranch().getId().toString();
//        String produkName = inventory.getName();
//        String produkCode = inventory.getCode();
//        Integer price100 = inventory.getPrice100();
//        Integer price90 = inventory.getPrice90();
//        Integer price60 = inventory.getPrice60();
//        Integer price = inventory.getPrice30();

          /*
                Fungsi onClick dibawah ini
           */
//        holder.detailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Fragment detail = new DetailProdukFragment();
//                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
//                arguments.putString("id", id);
//                detail.setArguments(arguments);
//                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainMenu_container, detail).commit();
//            }
//        });
//
//        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
//
//        if(inventory.getId() == 0){
//            holder.produkName.setText("Data sudah terhapus atau tidak ada");
//            holder.produkCode.setText("-");
//            holder.category.setText("-");
//            holder.warehouseCategory.setText("-");
//            holder.price100.setText("-");
//        }else {
//            try {
//                holder.produkName.setText(produkName);
//                holder.produkCode.setText(produkCode);
////                holder.category.setText(category);
////                holder.warehouseCategory.setText(warehouseCategory);
//                holder.price100.setText(formatter.format(price100) + "");
//            } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
//                ne.printStackTrace();
//            }
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int size = 0;
        try {
            size = mOrderList.size();
        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
            size = 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            size = 0;
        }
        return size;
    }

    /*
    VIEWHOLDER CLASS
     */
    public class RecyclerVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        Integer id;
        TextView produkName;
        TextView produkCode;
        TextView category;
        TextView warehouseCategory;
        TextView price100;
        TextView price90;
        TextView price60;
        TextView price30;
        EditText itemQuantity;
        Button detailButton;
        TextView buttonPlus;
        TextView buttonMinus;
        ImageView trashIcon;

        // ImageView imageView;

        public RecyclerVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            produkName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

            produkCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_code);

            category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_category);

            warehouseCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_warehouseCategory);

            price100 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            price90 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            price60 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            price30 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

            itemQuantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);

            buttonPlus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_button_plus);

            buttonMinus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_button_minus);

            detailButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_detail_button);

            trashIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.trash_icon);
            //imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my **`component_card_cart.xml`** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/first_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="INV/11/.../..."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.065" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardView4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.709" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_condition_label"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kondisi Barang :"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.368"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.586" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_condition"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100%"
        android:textColor="#8d021f"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.546"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.586" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_quantity_button_plus"
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#8d021f"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.667"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.601" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_quantity_button_minus"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="#8d021f"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.869"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.601" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nama Barang"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.479"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.336" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/item_quantity"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.798"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.632" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price_label"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Rp"
        android:textColor="#f88d69"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.32"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="200,000"
        android:textColor="#f88d69"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.579"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trash_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.956"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.565"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_trashbin_1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's my **`fragment_daftar_card.xml`** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Why you want id in fragment?

Comment: My objective is to sum value from EditText in RecyleView list.

Comment: You mean item_quantity ? Right?. You can do this with callbacks.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry to asked this, but how to implement callbacks to get sum value of item_quantity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add callback to your adapter -

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
   void getQuantity(String quantity);
}

void setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
    this.listener= listener ; 
}
```

Call listener's method form where you want to get value of quantity as below -

```
 listener.getQuantity(holder.itemQuantity.getText.toString());
```

Implement this listener in your fragment

```
public class DaftarCartFragment extends Fragment implements RecycleViewCartAdapter 
.OnItemClickListener  {

@Override
public void getQuantity(String quantity){
// required value is in quantity variable

}
}
```

Add below line above setAdapter method

```
 mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(DaftarCartFragment.this);
 rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer works fine on me. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Kindly upvote answer if it worked for you. It will help others too.